# React JSX transformer in Windows

Tags: windows, reactjs

It seems to do nothing? According to [this commit](https://github.com/spicyj/react/commit/0e2840abce0b211ef600b19ee7702efa431b8dae), the JSX transformer should work now.

The command I'm attempting to use at the moment:

```
C:\Node> node node_modules/react-tools/bin/jsx --watch S:/dev/_res/jsx/ S:/dev/_res/js/
```

Changing the `/` to `\` has no effect. Neither does double-quoting the paths.

When I run this command it returns with no errors and seems to have run fine. However absolutely nothing happens. I have some test JSX code in `C:\dev\_res\jsx\test.js` which should transpile after making a change.

Few extras tried now:

- Trying to convert a direct file, the executable spits out the proper usage doc
- Using option `-x js` has no effect
- `--harmony` has no effect

Comment: did you try `node_modules/react-tools/bin/jsx --watch C:\dev\_res\jsx C:\dev\_res\js` ?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Meaning moving all the files to the C: drive or changing them to backslashes? Backslashes yes, changing drives, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within how the JSX Tranformer deals with Windows drives. No error is thrown if the input/output directory contains a `:` and it simply returns with an exit code of 0.

If you're using a different drive for code from where the Node executable and node_modules directory lies, you need to mount the secondary drive to a folder ([good tutorial on how to do this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11253-mount-drives-partitions-folder.html)) and use the folder instead.

So in the path example above, it would go from:

```
C:\Node>node node_modules/react-tools/bin/jsx --watch S:/dev/_res/jsx/ S:/dev/_res/js/
```

to:

```
C:\Node>node node_modules/react-tools/bin/jsx --watch ../S/dev/_res/jsx/ ../S/dev/_res/js/
```

... if you mount the `S:` drive to a folder called `S` in your `C:` drive's root. The JSX Transformer will then proceed to process all files and continue to watch the directory as expected.