# Compiling jsx files on windows

Tags: reactjs

I have installed react-tools using npm:

```
npm -g install react-tools
```

I have a folder called "test", under which I have the folder containing the .jsx files, called "a1", and a destination directory to hold the .js files, called "a2". So I do this:

```
c:\test> jsx -w a1 a2
```

and it just displays [], probably meaning that it can't locate any files. On my Mac it works perfectly, but I'm working on a .Net project so I have to use windows.

I did look at the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191585/react-jsx-transformer-in-windows/27195567), but I'm still getting the same result. I have no problem using other tools, but I have to have my .jsx compiled to .js.

Comment: I don't know about react-tools, but the React project itself has transitioned to using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), which [supports JSX](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/jsx/), so you might want to give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Productionizing: Precompiled JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#productionizing-precompiled-jsx) docs:

> By default JSX files with a `.js` extension are transformed. Use `jsx --extension jsx src/ build/` to transform files with a `.jsx` extension.